# How do I configure Maven Cargo to use an embedded Tomcat 6 server?

Tags: maven-2, maven, maven-plugin, cargo, maven-cargo

I'm using Maven 3.0.3.  Is there a way I can use the Maven Cargo plugin to spin up an embedded Tomcat server?  Right now, it seems I have to install it myself first.  I get this error when I try and change the container type to "embedded" ...

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.cargo:cargo-maven2-plugin:1.1.2:run (default-cli) on project jx: Execution default-cli of goal org.codehaus.cargo:cargo-maven2-plugin:1.1.2:run failed: Cannot create configuration. There's no registered configuration for the parameters (container [id = [tomcat6x], type = [embedded]], configuration type [standalone]). Actually there are no valid types registered for this configuration. Maybe you've made a mistake spelling it? -> [Help 1]
```

The configuration that I used was ...

```
                            <plugins>
                                    <plugin>
                                            <groupId>org.codehaus.cargo</groupId>
                                            <artifactId>cargo-maven2-plugin</artifactId>
                                            <configuration>
                                                    <container>
                                                            <containerId>tomcat6x</containerId>
                                                            <type>embedded</type>
                                                    </container>

                                                    <configuration>
                                                            <properties>
                                                                    <cargo.servlet.port>8080</cargo.servlet.port>
                                                                    <cargo.logging>high</cargo.logging>
                                                            </properties>
```

Any help is appreciated.  The reason I'm not using the Maven embedded Tomcat plugin is that it doesn't support multiple deployment artifacts.  Thanks, - Dave

Comment: Updated for Tomcat 9: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59924534/how-to-run-embedded-tomcat-9-inside-maven-3-for-integration-testing-purposes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From cargo [documentation](http://cargo.codehaus.org/Tomcat+6.x) Embedded Container is not supported on tomcat6. It is only [supported](http://cargo.codehaus.org/Embedded+Container) for jetty.

Comment: This answer is outdated, embedded Tomcat is supported now.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the [t7mp](https://github.com/t7mp/t7mp) Plugin would be an alternative? The [Overview of the configuration options](https://github.com/t7mp/t7mp/wiki/Configuration---Overview) shows how to deploy multiple webapps and how to configure shared libs. As far as I know the current version is not available in maven central so you would have to download it from github and build and deploy it yourself.

When running it populates the `target/tomcat` folder with the libs of a specified tomcat 6 or 7 version and bootstrap tomcat using a new classloader in the same jvm.